# Setting Random seeds do not affect classification methods C5.0 and ctree

Tags: r, random, classification

I want to compare between two different classification methods, namely ctree and C5.0 in the libraries partyand c50 respectively, the comparison is to test their sensitivity to the initial start points. The test should be carried 30 times for each time the number of wrong classified items are calculated and stored in a vector then by using t-test I hope to see if they are really different or not.

```
library("foreign"); # for read.arff
library("party") # for ctree 
library("C50") # for C5.0 

trainTestSplit <- function(data, trainPercentage){
    newData <- list();
    all <- nrow(data);
    splitPoint <- floor(all * trainPercentage);
    newData$train <- data[1:splitPoint, ];
    newData$test <- data[splitPoint:all, ];
    return (newData);

}

ctreeErrorCount <- function(st,ss){
    set.seed(ss);
    model <- ctree(Class ~ ., data=st$train);
    class <- st$test$Class;
    st$test$Class <- NULL;
    pre = predict(model, newdata=st$test, type="response");
    errors <- length(which(class != pre)); # counting number of miss classified items
    return(errors);
}
C50ErrorCount <- function(st,ss){
    model <- C5.0(Class ~ ., data=st$train, seed=ss);
    class <- st$test$Class;
    pre = predict(model, newdata=st$test, type="class");
    errors <- length(which(class != pre)); # counting number of miss classified items
    return(errors);
}

compare <- function(n = 30){
    data <- read.arff(file.choose());

    set.seed(100);
    errors = list(ctree = c(), c50 = c());
    seeds <- floor(abs(rnorm(n) * 10000));
    for(i in 1:n){
        splitData <- trainTestSplit(data, 0.66);
        errors$ctree[i] <- ctreeErrorCount(splitData, seeds[i]);
        errors$c50[i] <- C50ErrorCount(splitData, seeds[i]);
    }

    cat("\n\n");
    cat("============= ctree Vs C5.0 =================\n");
    cat(paste(errors$ctree, "            ", errors$c50, "\n"))
    tt <- t.test(errors$ctree, errors$c50);
    print(tt);

}
```

The program shown is supposedly doing the job of comparison, but because of the number of errors does not change in the vectors then the t.test function produces an error. I used iris inside R (but changing class to Class) and [Winchester breast cancer](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Original%29) data which can be downloaded [here](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pqf/data/wisconsin.arff) to test it but any data can be used as long as it has Class attribute

But I get in to the problem that the result of both methods remain constant and not changes while I am changing the random seed, theoretically ,as described in their documentation,both of the functions use random seeds, ctree uses `set.seed(x)` while C5.0 uses an argument called seed to set seed, unfortunatly I can not find the effect.

Could you please tell me how to control initials of these functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ctrees does only depend on a random seed in the case where you configure it to use a random selection of input variables (ie that mtry > 0 within ctree_control). See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf (p. 11)

In regards to C5.0-trees the seed is used this way:

```
  ctrl = C5.0Control(sample=0.5, seed=ss);
  model <- C5.0(Class ~ ., data=st$train, control = ctrl);
```

Notice that the seed is used to select a sample of the data, not within the algoritm itself. See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/C50.pdf (p. 5)